# String Contain Substring or not in Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, netbeans, compare

Actually i am facing a problem in comparing string in java. The problem is that i have Arraylist type list which contain some employee designation but designation may be developer or Junior developer or may be Sinior developer type designation my problem that consider all developer designation as a only developer so i use this code for this.

```
ArrayList<String> al_designation = ret.getDesignationListFromRegistration();
int ii = 0;
for (String designation : al_designation) {
    ii++;
    for (int j = ii; j < al_designation.size(); j++) {
        if (designation.toLowerCase().contains(al_designation.get(j).toLowerCase())) {
            al_designation.remove(j);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

What i want all HELPER type designation consider only HELPER, Same for STITCHER all type STITCHER.

Comment: What this _actually_ looks like is you should have a `Designation` class, and have sublasses `DeveloperDesignation`, `SeniodDeveloperDesignation`, etc.

Comment: no this just a list which contain all designation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add required items from your ArrayList to a HashMap as follows:

```
    ArrayList<String> al_designation = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Developer", "Junior Developer",
            "Senior Developer", "Senior Architect", "Junior Manager", "Senior Manager", "Assistant Manager", //
            "CEO", "Tech Lead", "Dev Lead"));
    System.out.println(al_designation);// Before it contains all
                                        // designations.

    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String designation : al_designation) {
        designation = designation.toLowerCase();
        String[] words = designation.split(" ");
        String lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
        String value = map.get(lastWord);
        if (value == null)
            map.put(lastWord, designation);
        else
            map.put(lastWord, lastWord);
    }
    al_designation.clear();
    al_designation.addAll(map.values());
    System.out.println(al_designation);// Now it contains only required designations. 
                                        //This is your answer.
```

Comment: Thanks, Man and all for giving me your valuable time my problem is solve now.

Comment: Can you mark it as "Accepted' whichever answer helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, accepting an answer to a question you’ve asked doesn’t require any reputation. Only voting does.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what are you trying to accomplish however you can check if your string e.g. "Junior developer" contains substring "developer" like this:

```
if (str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase())){
    // do whatever you need to do
}
```